# geom_contour and stat_contour fail

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a simple contour plot, similar to the example [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_contour.html). However, it fails with "Computation failed in `stat_contour()`: no proper 'z' matrix specified".

```
library('MASS')
library('tidyverse')
```

generate a gaussian density:

```
den = kde2d(x = rnorm(10000), y = rnorm(10000), h=.5, n=100)
zdf = data.frame(den$z)
colnames(zdf) = den$y
zdf$x = den$x
```

melt similar to documentation example:

```
melted = melt(zdf, id.vars = 'x', variable.name = 'y', value.name='z')
colnames(melted)
# [1] "x" "y" "z"
dim(melted)
# [1] 10000   3

ggplot(melted, aes(x, y, z=z)) + stat_contour()
# Warning message:
# Computation failed in `stat_contour()`:
# no proper 'z' matrix specified
```

'melted' seems to be formatted exactly the same as the volcano example, with x as the fast index and one entry in z for each unique combination of x and y. I can't figure out what the difference is.

Answer (score 1):

When melting, the column names were cast to integer type in the y column (although they still print as though doubles?) Adding the following line fixed the problem:

```
melted$y = as.double(melted$y)
```